# if apache pulsar is a push model whether will it send notification to consumers when the message received from producer?

Tags: apache-pulsar

Would like to know apache pulsar has the functionality to send notification to its consumers those who subscribed? or only it will send messages when consumer requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Pulsar, consumers signal to the broker how many messages they can receive. When a new message arrives from a producer, the broker will dispatch it to a consumer that has available space. So there is no need to notify the consumer, the message is sent automatically.